# Find $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

Tags: probability

This is probably an easy question to solve. I'm preparing an exam and got stuck here, would really appreciate some help.

$A$ and $B$ are two events, $P(A) > P(B)$; $P(A \vee B) = 0.626$, $P(A \wedge B)= 0.144$; also $A$ and $B$ are independent.

How can I find $P(A)$ and $P(B)$?

I know that since they're independent events, $P(A \wedge B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$

So

$0.144 = P(A) \cdot P(B)$

Also

$P(A \vee B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \wedge B)$, so

$0.626 = P(A) + P(B) - 0.144$

But I cant find a way to obtain $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ from there. I don't know how to relate that $P(A) > P(B)$

Thanks

Comment: You haven't used the fact that they are independent yet...

Comment: Since they're independent, P(A and B) = P(A).P(B)...

Comment: You know P(A) + P(B), and you know P(A)P(B). If it helps, think of the general algebra problem of determing $x$ and $y$, if you know $xy$ and $x + y$.

Comment: I get stuck there, in the equation system being:
0,77=x+y
0,144=xy

Comment: $x=(0.77-y)\implies 0.144=(0.77-y)y$. Go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have $P(A) + P(B) = 0.77$, then $P(A) = 0.77 - P(B)$. Also, you know that $P(A)P(B) = 0.144$.

Replacing $P(A)$ in $P(A)P(B) = 0.144$, you'll get $(0.77 - P(B))P(B) = 0.144$. Then, you'll get the quadratic equation : $$0.77P(B) - P(B)^2 - 0.144 = 0$$

The solutions are : $P(B) = 0.32$ and $P(B) = 0.45$.

Replacing them in $P(A)P(B) = 0.144$, you'll get $P(A) = 0.45$ or $P(A) = 0.32$.

Thus, if you choose $P(B) = 0.32$, you'll get $P(A) = 0.45$.

Hope this helps you.